# QMessageBox does not display - PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

my OK message box in the function `closeit` does not want to show up and it fails the whole app. This is the simplified code. What am I missing?

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QFileDialog, QLabel, QCheckBox, QWidget, QMessageBox

class MyDialog(object):  
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
            Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
            Dialog.resize(800, 300)        
            self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
            self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 150, 300, 50))
            self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
            _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
            Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Action"))  
            self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Do it!"))    
            self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.closeit)

        def closeit(self):
          QMessageBox().warning(self, "DONE!", "Hasta la vista!", QMessageBox.Ok)
```

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication
from somecode import MyDialog

class AppWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = MyDialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.show()  

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = AppWindow()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @eyllanesc mind explaining? this was not much helpful. Other parts of GUI show well. Only messagebox does not show.

Comment: 1) add `self.retranslateUi(Dialog)` after `self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")` 2) change `QMessageBox().warning(self, "DONE!", "Hasta la vista!", QMessageBox.Ok)` to `QMessageBox.warning(None, "DONE!", "Hasta la vista!", QMessageBox.Ok)`

Comment: 1) The first error is that you have never called the retranslateUi method so you have never made the connection between the clicked signal and the closeit method (you can also see that on the button that does not have text)

Comment: 2) QMessageBox.question requires a widget as a first parameter or None, but MyDialog is not so it will throw you an error, so the solution is to pass it to you None

Comment: The 1) is obviously an involuntary error because pyuic if you use it, instead 2) is the background error and therefore point to the duplicate where it explains what I have pointed out in my previous comment. I recommend you read https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html#using-the-generated-code

Comment: As a last recommendation do not modify the code generated by pyuic, for example the logic of the logic of the clicked you could do it in AppWindow and you would not have had any problem.

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Comment: It seems strange to me that in less than 2 minutes of marking your question as a duplicate, you discard all the answers of the other question. Have you understood the other answers? If you have not done it then do not say that they are not helpful, better question about the parts that you did not understand. The underlying problem is well explained in the other answer, but also you have a trivial error: you deleted code that you should not have deleted.

Comment: Do not be so quick to comment, take time. For example, while you were commenting, I was trying to explain why I think your question is a duplicate. I recommend you read [ask] and pass the [tour]

Comment: I will do better next time! Much appreciated!